# ZF2 and DB2 connection issue

Tags: zend-framework2, db2, database-connection

I have setup DB2 Database on a Ubuntu System. I have successfully login & create a database into DB2 instance. Also inserted some records.

Now I have setup a ZF2 Application on same server and want application connect to DB2 instance. After read some online docs, I get configuration settings like this.

```
'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($sm) use ($dbParams) {
    return new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
        'driver'    => 'IbmDb2',
        'hostname'  => '*LOCAL',
        'database'  => 'dbname',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'driver_options' => array(
            'i5_naming' => 'DB2_I5_NAMING_ON',
            'i5_libl' => '*LIBL'
        ),
        'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false)
    ));
},
```

But that give warning

```
Warning: db2_connect() [<a href='function.db2-connect'>function.db2-connect</a>]:  Incorrect option setting passed in
```

And give empty resultset.

Then after I commented out both options in `driver_options` . Now warning gone, But still result set is empty. I also tried commenting out hostname, but that has no impact on result set.

As it is Ubuntu System instead of IBM Machine, If their could be different settings to connect ?

UPDATE : Problem resolved, Explanation in Answer my myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : Problem resolved, It is much problem of how DB2 return records. DB2 return fields in upper cases, While my ZF2 application Models handles in lower cases. So no records shown in listing. I need to add a option in Database settings like below it to work.

```
'driver_options' => array(
    'DB2_ATTR_CASE' => DB2_CASE_LOWER
),
```